# Installing and booting Linux Deepin on external Hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a external hard drive with 1TB of memory on it. My question is if I can install Linux Deepin on this hard drive, and then plug it into my computer and boot from the hard drive, while still saving all my files and such on it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a partition with Deepin on (on the hard drive) make it bootable and then boot from that partition with the OS on, install it on which ever partition or hard drive you want and then you're done. 
I haven't yet seen anyone be able to have files and a bootable ISO on the same partition yet, but who knows, it could work.

Tl;dr make a partition on the HD for Deepin and then the other partition for the files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do.

In my case I've Deepin 20.6 I installed in dual booting: First Windows 10 and second Deepin OS.

After that I decided sell my computer but it was exhausting install and configurate everyhting then I take one decision: I remove the master hard disk drive from the laptop and I connected via USB 2.0 enclosure.

Finally, I go to UEFI configuration and place the boot order with 1st option "USB Boot" When I turn on the computer said "Welcome to GRUB" and listed my Deepin OS, my Windows 10 and the other Windows 10 Installed in the permanent HDD on my laptop.